# Consider a random variable X, find its PMF

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

[image]

This question has me stumped. I'm fairly certain that the answer to part a.) is pretty simple: $P(X>n+m|X>n)=\frac{P(X>n+m)}{P(X>n)}$, because $X>n+m$ is a subset of $X>n$, which is $\frac{a^{n+m}}{a^n}=a^m$. But part b.) is where I run out of steam. What avenue should I be taking? It's the inequality that's confusing me. I can't see how to obtain $P(X=x)$ from $P(X>n)$ and $P(X>n+m)$.

Comment: I already told you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2710080/75923): $P(X=x)=P(X>x-1)-P(X>x)=a^{x-1}-a^{x}$ for $x>0$. Further $P(X=0)=1-P(X>0)=1-a^0=1-1=0$

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @drhab sorry, I didn't really follow your answer - my ignorance. I thought I'd clear up any ambiguity by sharing the full question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for c):

If $X$ is a random variable that only takes values in $\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ then:

$$\mathsf EX=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathsf P(X>n)$$

This on base of:$$p_1+2p_2+3p_3+\cdots=(p_1+p_2+p_3+\dots)+(p_2+p_3+\cdots)+(p_3+\cdots)+\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Pr(X>0)=a^0=1  \rightarrow \Pr(X=0)=0$$

$$\Pr(X=1)=\Pr(X>0)-\Pr(X>1)=1-a $$
$$\Pr(X=2)=\Pr(X>1)-\Pr(X>2)=a-a^2 $$
$$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(X>2)-\Pr(X>3)=a^2-a^3 $$
...
$$\Pr(X=k)=\Pr(X>k-1)-\Pr(X>k)=a^{k-1}-a^k $$

Comment: How about part (c)?

Comment: Thank you! This cleared it up for me totally. Very clear and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @GNUSupporter $\mathsf E(X) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathsf P(X>n)$